# Joda-Time String to LocalTime 24-hour equivalent

Tags: java, date, time, jodatime

I have this time. 8:32:00 PM. How do I convert this to a 24hr [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) LocalTime format? There's no time converter in the Joda-Time library

Comment: The value of the time and the format are separate concepts. Start by parsing the `String` to `LocalTime` and then formatting it the way you want

Comment: Once I converted the time to a localtime how do I convert it to its equivalent 24hr format? in this case, 8:32:00 PM is 20:32:00?

Comment: Use a `DateTimeFormatter`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start by parsing the `String` to a `LocalTime`...

```
String timeValue = "8:32:00 PM";
DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("h:mm:ss a").toFormatter();
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timeValue, parseFormat);
```

Then format the result...

```
DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("H:mm:ss").toFormatter();
String formatted = localTime.toString(outputFormat);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Which will output `20:32:00`

Remember, the value of `LocalTime` and the format are two separate concepts, you can't affect the "format" of the `LocalTime` object itself, you can only translate the concept of the value to a `String` representation (via a formatter)

Comment: but what if my time is in this kind of format? "8:32 PM"?

Comment: @user962206 What do you mean?  The `String` value is `8:32 PM`?  Then you need to change the `parseFormat` to meet your requirements

Comment: @MadProgrammer Your code for generating the String representation can be much simpler. The Joda-Time `LocalTime` class has overloaded [the `toString` method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#toString(java.lang.String)) to take a String for the pattern. `String formatted = localTime.toString( "H:mm:ss" );` The entire line for the formatter can be deleted.

Comment: @BasilBourque That's true, I was deliberately taking the long road for demonstration purposes...I was also getting cross over from Java 8, so I was pedantic to be sure

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question,

> Once I converted the time to a localtime how do I convert it to its equivalent 24hr format?

You would use [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) to create a `DateTimeFormatter`, like so -

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String str = fmt.print(dt);
```

Excerpted from the linked javadoc,

> ```
> H       hour of day (0~23)           number        0
> m       minute of hour               number        30
> s       second of minute             number        55
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to *convert* the time (they're the same time), you want to *format* the time. Joda has a DateTimeFormatter class (see http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html for details).

You can use it something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String str = date.toString(fmt);
```